# how to deserialize a collection from an alamofire request

Tags: swift, alamofire

this is a pretty basic question of the syntax for deserializing responsejson collection in alamofire and swift

I have a GET service that returns an array of user objects e.g.

```
[
  {"uname": "bob"},
  {"uname": "jane"}
]
```

and here is my request

```
   Alamofire.request(.GET, url , encoding:.JSON)
     .responseJSON(options: .MutableContainers, completionHandler:{ (request, response, JSON, error) -> Void in
        let result = JSON as? [Dictionary<String,String>]
        if (response!.statusCode == 200 && error == nil){
           //how should I deserialize the result here to return [String]
           callback(success: true, errorMsg: nil, friends:friends)
         }
         else{
           callback(success: false,errorMsg:error?.localizedDescription,friends:nil)
          }
    })
```

My question is how to deserialize the result, and am I correct to assume that the json result is a [Dictionary] and in order for me to change it to a [String] result, should I map it?

If I use the map syntax below I have a few questions

```
let friends = result?.map {
                    return $0["uname"] as String?
                }
```

With the optional return value can I get it to return a [String] instead of a [String?] in a graceful way - isn't there a way to let map return only non null values somehow in a concise syntax?

Also is there a better syntax for map that lets me name the parameters instead of using $0?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I use Alamofire with SwiftyJSON to do the job and deserialise array of JSON objects to native objects. Here is an example of how I do it:

```
Alamofire.request(request)
        .responseJSON(options: nil) { (request, response, json, error) -> Void in
            if let requestError = error as NSError?{
                callback!(nil, nil, requestError)
            }
            if let httpResponse = response as NSHTTPURLResponse?{
                if(httpResponse.statusCode != 200){
                    callback!(nil, httpResponse, nil)
                } else{
                    let jsonResult = JSON(json!) as JSON
                    var concerts = self.deserializeConcerts(jsonResult)
                    callback!(concerts, nil, nil)
                }                
            }
        }
```

Deserialize concerts looks like this:

```
class private func deserializeConcerts(concerts: SwiftyJSON.JSON) -> [ConcertModel]{
        let concertsArray = concerts.object as! NSMutableArray
        var concertObjs = [ConcertModel]()
        for concert in concertsArray{
            let concertObj = ConcertModel(concert: concert as! NSDictionary)
            concertObjs.append(concertObj)
        }
        return concertObjs
    }
```

And finally, `ConcertModel` initialiser just maps the values of the NSDictionary to the properties of the ConcertModel object.

Answer (score 1):

Updated implementation for Alamofire 4.3

```
Alamofire.request(url, method: .get)
  .responseJSON { response in
      if response.data != nil {
        let json = JSON(data: response.data!)
        let name = json["data"][0]["name"].string
        if name != nil {
          print(name!)
        }
      }
  }
```

That will parse this JSON input:

```
{
  data: [
    { name: 'John' },
    { name: 'Dave' }
  ]
}
```